# How to pull data from firestore and display on the screen in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a flutter project. I am using firebase as the backend of my application. I want to pull data from firebase and display in the screen. I want to pull data from firebase firestore and display to the screen.

Since i am new to flutter, i don't know how to achieve this. Can someone help me out in this case?

It would be great if ya'll can attach any reference links?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you check the docs ?

Comment: Yes, But could't still figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sit down and read the documentation of flutter fire, which is complete and well explained [You can start here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage) and if you want videos, there is a good resource [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ).

Comment: I went through this, but i don't understand how to connect it with the userID provided by firebase.

Comment: I like to learn with videos, this one will help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWy9ylc3f9U

Answer (score 0):

so I understand and it's totally normal to be lost sometimes. Open the FlutterFire documentation or try YouTube, connect your application to your Firebase database at first. Then you should use the syntax/API they provide for showing text or something. At first, fetch the value then store it in your local variable then show that variable in your Text(variable_here).